# Extra quotes in ServiceStack POST

Tags: json, angularjs, servicestack, quotes

I am using ServiceStack 3.9 with AngularJS. I am trying to do a POST like this:

```
$http.post('web.ashx/addUser', data)
```

"data" is a correct JSON object.

However, when ServiceStack POST is executed, I get double quotes in every string property of my DTO object:

```
"\"John\""
```

instead of

```
"John"
```

I have tried to configure ServiceStack JSON serializer, but I am not able to fix it.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you parsing the json object?

Comment: I dont manipulate it. It has this format:name:"John", surname:"Smith"

Comment: I am asking on the server side?

Comment: No, on the server side I dont parse it. I guess ServiceStack does it for me.

Comment: the problem is on the server side right?

Comment: Yes, on the server side is where I get the wrong format ("\"John\"" instead of "John")

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JsonObject.Parse(objectToParse)` on the sever side after you get the post data it might solve your problem.

Comment: How can I JsonObject.Parse(objectToParse)? My Post method at server side is: public void Post(UserRequest request). "request" is already a c# class, but with its properties have double extra quotes.

Comment: If i post the data like this: $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: 'web.ashx/addUser',
                    data: {
                        name: 'John'
                    }
                })); server side gets the property name in the wright formar ("John"). However, if I post $http.post('web.ashx/addUser', data), it doesn't. Do you know what is the difference?

Comment: You can take a look at `transformRequest` of $http that might be helpful to you.